# ELMAH log how to ignore error by type

Tags: asp.net, elmah

Hello I have setup ELMAH in my project, but I am getting a lot errors like

> System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value
>   was detected from the client (:).
>
> Generated: Sun, 26 May 2013 21:46:30 GMT
>
> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).    at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext
>   context)

I would like to ignore them, and don't send to my mail but write in ELMAH DB.
Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using [error filtering](https://elmah.github.io/a/error-filtering/) in ELMAH and which is [described in detail on the project wiki](https://elmah.github.io/a/error-filtering/). In short, the following filter in your `web.config` should do the job (assuming you have setup the modules configuration sections already):

```
<errorFilter>
    <test>
        <and>
            <regex binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail" />
            <regex binding="Exception.Message" 
               pattern="(?ix: \b potentially \b.+?\b dangerous \b.+?\b value \b.+?\b detected \b.+?\b client \b )" />
        </and>
    </test>
</errorFilter>
```

The first `<regex>` condition [filters based on the filtering source](https://elmah.github.io/a/error-filtering/#filtering-by-source) such that mailing will not occur. [Check out the documentation on the wiki for full details](https://elmah.github.io/a/error-filtering/#filtering-by-source).

Comment: I can't get it to stop sending "System.InvalidOperationException: The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL." My pattern is: 
<test>
        <and>
          <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
          <regex binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail" />
        </and>
      </test>
      <test>
        <and>
          <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="(?ix: \b requested  \b.+?\b resource  \b.+?\b accessed  \b.+?\b SSL \b )" />
          <regex binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail"/>
        </and>
      </test>

Comment: @RhysStephens You are supposed to have one `<test>` node so the second one is getting ignored. You need to `<or>` together your 404 & message pattern cases and then `<and>` that together with the mail source case. Why don't you post it as another question here on SO or on the [ELMAH Discussion Group](http://groups.google.com/group/elmah) and we can take it from there?

Answer (score 18):

A solution that doesn't involve regular expressions, simply add this to your Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message == "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).")
        e.Dismiss();
}

// this method may also be useful
protected void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message == "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).")
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Or you can combine the two methods:

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    Filter(args);
}

void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    Filter(args);
}

void Filter(ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Exception.GetBaseException() is HttpRequestValidationException)
        args.Dismiss();
}
```

Comment: This does the opposite of what the question asks in my codebase. I still sends the email but doesn't log to the database.

Comment: There are two functions, one for filtering from the log, and another to filter for email. Need to use the ErrorMail_Filtering function not ErrorLog_Filtering to remove from email, as per https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering

Comment: For some reason the `args.Exception.GetBaseException() is HttpRequestValidationException` did not evaluate true. So I suggest checking the message property of the exception to see if it contains the error.